# Film about alien/android that molds facial features

Tags: story-identification, movie, androids

I'm trying to identify a scifi film from the 60s or 70s about an android (or possibly alien) that was awoken and had to create his own facial features before. He was some kind of guardian of the human race and explained to one of the characters that he was the last of his line, they were in a cave and there was a long line of bodies of previous androids laid out and the space for one more. I can't remember anything else about the plot but this has bugged me for years!

Comment: What does "mounds" mean? Is that a typo, and if so, for what?

Comment: I assume the OP meant 'molds'.

Answer (score 11):

Pretty sure you're looking for The Questor Tapes, a 1974 TV movie, created by Gene Rodenberry. It starred Robert Foxworth as the android, the last of his kind. Who explains to Mike Farrell (who starred in MASH), one of the scientists, who helped put him together, that he's a guardian of the human race. I believe his actual creator was a previous android, passing as human, who had enlisted the help of the government to build him. There's the scene of the cavern with the earlier androids.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's exactly the movie. I have been trying to find it for years! Thanks! By the way, you can stream it here: https://archive.org/details/the-questor-tapes