# What was the name of 1960ish movie about an android that had to find its creator before its internal H-bomb would make it blow up

Tags: story-identification

I recall this old sci fi movie where a android is looking for its' "father", it will self destruct if not found in 7 days. The father knows how to defuse the H-bomb in it. Then it goes on to save humanity

Comment: We're going to need a few more details than that. Take a look at [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337) guide to see if you can [edit] in any more details.

Comment: So probably not Eve of Destruction (http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/EveOfDestruction)?

Comment: The closest I've seen to this is a b-movie called suspect device, but that was a 90's picture (unless it was a remake of an earlier film). The android was carrying a nuke but it wasn't an h-bomb, and his creator admitted he couldn't remove/disable the bomb without dismantling "killing" the android. In the end the android chooses to blow up taking his creator and some military bigwig with him.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probable duplicate of this question; [Film about alien/android that molds facial features](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116042/film-about-alien-android-that-molds-facial-features/116050#116050).
The Questor Tapes, created by Gene Rodenberry. Robert Foxworth stars as the android, who needs to find his father/creator, who can defuse his nuclear generator before it overloads and explodes.He becomes the current guardian of humanity

[image]

Comment: Definitely a better match than my answer. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

On the off chance you're confused about details (or someone else is looking for a film about an android looking for their creator while they have a bomb in them), I'm going to propose *[Eve of Destruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eve_of_Destruction_(film))*, a 1991 film about a gynoid named EVE VIII designed for military operations and looking identical to her creator, Dr. Eve Simmons. EVE is damaged during a bank robbery, which triggers embedded memories from her creator, and a desire to seek out Dr. Simmons's father, who was abusive to her as a child. EVE indeed does have a nuclear bomb in her, which must be disarmed, triggered to go off within 24 hours after she gets into a car crash.

Areas where it doesn't match up are a later time frame, possibly a different gender for the android, and that the father and creator are different people. Also, EVE doesn't go to save humanity, but defeating her does save a significant part of the population around her.

### Trailer